# Getting *current* members of US Congress via the GPO API?

Tags: usa, api

The Government Printing Office API [What's Available](https://www.govinfo.gov/help/whats-available) site links to the [Congressional Directory](https://www.govinfo.gov/help/cdir), but the most recent CD available appears to be the 115th (2017-2018).  Does anybody know if this is intended behavior, or if there is another GPO collection that contains listings for the 116th Congress (2019-2020)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For Future Reference

[Posed this question as an Issue](https://github.com/usgpo/api/issues/53) on the GPO GitHub repo, got this as an answer:

> This has not been added to the system yet. Once the volume has been printed, it will also be added to govinfo and made available via the API.
>
> The U.S. Code section indicates that this is to be printed and distributed "as early as practicable". My understanding is that information is still being compiled.
>
> The first edition of the CDIR for the 115th Congress was made available in June 2018.